# When does @GenerateValue in hibernate execute

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using an `@Entity` with a `CrudRepository` to create an entry in my MySQL database, and I was wondering at what point the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) execute and generate the auto increment value?

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "all_contacts")
    public class Contact {

      //Ideally this would be set as foreign key to application's user schema
      private long userId;

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column( name="contactid")
      private long contactId;

      @NotNull
      private String name;

   //getters and setters

    }
```

//

```
 public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> { }
```

I ask because I want to access the value of the `contactId` through its getter, but do I have to wait until the `ContactRepository.save()` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't know the new assigned id of that entity prior to executing the SQL INSERT statement.

So, yes you need to `ContactRepository.save()` or any command that trigger SQL INSERT statement before can get that id. But save is better because it is guaranteed that it will always return ID.

Answer (score 0):

We get the generated value once SQL insert statement is executed. We can't know the value is being assinged before save(). **GenerationType.AUTO** number generator generates automatic object IDs for entity objects and this generated numeric value is used for primary key field.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) int id;

}
```